# KL divergence between two normal distributions can be negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, divergence-theorem

KL Divergence between two normal distributions can be negative?

There are many derivations of KL divergence of two normal distribution.
The equation is as follows:

$$D_{KL}(p||q) = \frac{1}{2}\biggl[log\frac{|\sum_{q}|}{|\sum_{p}|} -k + (\mu_{p} - \mu_{p})^T\sum\nolimits_{q}^{-1}(\mu_{p} - \mu_{p}) + tr(\sum\nolimits_{q}^{-1}\sum\nolimits_{p})\biggr]$$
$$k \text{ is the dimension of normal distribution}$$
$$\mu_p \text{ is the mean of the normal distribution } p$$
$$\mu_q \text{ is the mean of the normal distribution } q$$

Far as I know, KL divergence is always greater than or equal to 0. My question is the equation above can be negative? (Actually, I implemented it, but I am frequently getting negative results)

Comment: I bet there's an implementation error.

Comment: I would check the numerical errors, and conditionness of the matrices $\sigma_q$, $\sigma_p$. If you are dealing with a rather large matrices, there can be noticeable numerical errors due to the finite precision, which may cause the issue.